# How to Mimic SQL Developer Database Copy Feature Behavior Through Scripting

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

[SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) has a feature "Database Copy". I had initially thought that maybe it uses [SQL*Plus COPY Command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/apb.htm#CHDEAEDE) under the hood. However, this doesn't appear to be the case, as you can copy CLOB's through the SQL Developer option. Any ideas on what it uses, and how one could possibly script out a copy using the same methods? I find the feature to work really well when compared to some other database development IDEs for copying data.

Comment: Data pump runs into issues many times when trying to migrate data between different database versions. Also data pump requires permissions beyond read access to your tables in order to export data.